# How to implement js widget in an angular 5 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular5

How to implement js widget in an angular 5 application. I dont have any background in both angular and js. Any help?

Widget is already working. The problem is how it will work in angular 5 app.

Can anyone share the guide lines on how to implement this one?. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Please post what you've tried in code

Comment: first i reference the js and css on index.html

Comment: You can update your question by clicking on edit and post your code in your question.

Comment: im not allow to add photo or code it say i need to earn something.